# How to edit field values in sqLite using Qt Gui app?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I am writting a library application using Qt 5.7 and C++ backed by a sqLite v3 database. I want to implement a loan/return functionality. I have enabled a bool field in my database called isLoaned and i want to change its value of the corresponding record to true whenever the user clicks the loan button. I get a proper connection to the database and no errors, but the database is not updated and field value remain the same. I followed Qt documenation about the use of these classes, but i cant find a solution. 
Here is my code
:

```
void loanBookDialog::on_loanBookBtn_clicked()
{
MainWindow mw;
mw.connOpen();
QString id, title;
id = ui->idLnEdit->text();
title = ui->titleLnEdit->text();
QSqlQuery qry(mw.myDb);
qry.prepare("select * from Books where (id='"+id+"' OR title='"+title+"') AND isLoaned=0");
if (qry.exec()) {
    QSqlRecord loanRec(qry.record());
    QSqlField loanField = loanRec.field(5);
    loanField.setValue(true);
    qDebug() << loanField.isNull();
    qDebug() << loanField.isReadOnly();
    qDebug() << loanField.isValid();
    qDebug() << loanField.isGenerated();
    ui->wrong5Lbl->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color: green}");
    ui->wrong5Lbl->setText("Loaned succesfuly.");
    mw.connClose();
}
else {
    ui->wrong5Lbl->setStyleSheet("QLabel {color: red}");
    ui->wrong5Lbl->setText("Oops! Something went wrong, try again.");
}
}
```

**Debug output:**

```
Field value: QVariant(bool, true)
isNull: false
isReadOnly: false
isValid: true
isGenerated: true
```

Comment: You are already using prepare. So for $deity's sake, use PARAMETERS too! Creating SQL by concatenating strings is fraught with peril.

Comment: The above code is not ever even trying to update the field. Do you think it does, or should do?

Comment: I dont think i quite understood, can you provide a code sample? Thanks.

Comment: yes i think it would, by using setValue() on the field

Comment: I can't provide a code sample without knowing what you expected.

Comment: I expect to edit the field value, what is wrong in the case here?

Comment: what is wrong is that QSqlRecord is not a reference to the database. It is simply a result of the query. Copied. Updating it has no effect.

Comment: Note that `QSqlRecord`s obtained from `QSqlTableModel` _are_ references and `QSqlTableModel` _can_ generate and execute the statements for you. But the ones from `QSqlQuery` are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL queries, in any database, return the results *by value*. The `QSqlRecord` is a *copy* of the database, not a reference to it. Therefore `loanField.setValue(true);` achieves absolutely nothing.

To modify the content of the database, you need to execute a data modification statement, in this case an [update](http://sqlite.org/lang_update.html).

Also, please keep in mind that composing queries using string composition is fraught with peril due to quoting issues and should *never be used* where parameters can be.

```
QSqlQuery loanQuery(mw.myDb);
loanQuery.prepare("update Books set isLoaned where id=:id");
// note: you can re-use the prepared query with different bindings to improve performance
loanQuery.bindValue(":id", id);
loanQuery.exec();
```

Also, don't forget to wrap it in transaction. Do:

```
mw.myDb.transation();
```

before and

```
mw.myDb.commit();
```

after. And check errors! If commit fails, the data was not written!

Comment: This is true if you're using `QSqlRecord`. But you can use one of the SQL data models that are writable, and then `setData` will do the right thing.

Comment: @KubaOber, actually I believe those models also use `QSqlRecord`. Just not `QSqlQuery`.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the models use, not really. As long as they implement `setData`, they'll modify the database as desired.

Comment: @KubaOber, model does matter. `QSqlQuery` returns a copy, calling `setData` on it's result has no effect.

Comment: I'm talking about a **model** - something that derives from `QAbstractItemModel`. E.g. `QSqlTableModel` implements `setData` and it most certainly **is** editable. Try it out if you don't believe me. I'm not talking about `SQqlQuery` or `QSqlRecord`.

Comment: @KubaOber, `QSqlQueryModel` **does** derive `QAbstractItemModel`, but it does **not** implement `setData`.

Comment: That's why I mentioned `QSqlTableModel`. The way to use it would be on a view, and implementing proper triggers in the view to make it writable. That way you don't need to use `QSqlQueryModel` :)

Comment: @KubaOber, yes, `QSqlTableModel` would work. But not _any_ model. And using `QSqlTableModel` on a view and defining the trigger does not sound exactly simpler then updating manually. You have to write the DML to update either way.